# UFW - How to make it easier and what are stealth ports can UFW have these?

Tags: firewall, iptables, ufw, logging, gufw

Let me show u what I jusat wasted 2 hours doing:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         REJECT      Anywhere
23/tcp                     REJECT      Anywhere
79/tcp                     REJECT      Anywhere
25/tcp                     REJECT      Anywhere
43/tcp                     REJECT      Anywhere
49                         REJECT      Anywhere
21/tcp                     REJECT      Anywhere
110                        REJECT      Anywhere
115/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
39/udp                     REJECT      Anywhere
143                        REJECT      Anywhere
161                        REJECT      Anywhere
199                        REJECT      Anywhere
209                        REJECT      Anywhere
213                        REJECT      Anywhere
530/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
389                        REJECT      Anywhere
444                        REJECT      Anywhere
465/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
512/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
513/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
514/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
514/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
540/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
554                        REJECT      Anywhere
556/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
623/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
706                        REJECT      Anywhere
88                         REJECT      Anywhere
990/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
994                        REJECT      Anywhere
995                        REJECT      Anywhere
993                        REJECT      Anywhere
130/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
130/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
131/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
132/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
133/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
134/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
135/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
136/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
137/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
138/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
139/udp                    REJECT      Anywhere
139/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
138/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
137/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
136/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
135/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
134/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
133/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
132/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
131/tcp                    REJECT      Anywhere
22 (v6)                    REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
23/tcp (v6)                REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
79/tcp (v6)                REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
43/tcp (v6)                REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
49 (v6)                    REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
110 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
115/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
39/udp (v6)                REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
143 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
161 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
199 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
209 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
213 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
530/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
389 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
444 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
465/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
512/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
513/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
514/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
514/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
540/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
554 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
556/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
623/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
706 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
88 (v6)                    REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
990/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
994 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
995 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
993 (v6)                   REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
130/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
130/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
131/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
132/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
133/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
134/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
135/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
136/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
137/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
138/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
139/udp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
139/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
138/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
137/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
136/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
135/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
134/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
133/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
132/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
131/tcp (v6)               REJECT      Anywhere (v6)
```

Followed by installing fail2ban I did this all manually from wiki ports page list and typing every single reject command!

I still probably missed another 60000

Comment: How can i program this into a code like a .bat file like on ms-dos?  It takes me like a week to setup ubuntu - install remove configure - i wanna make my own program to do it

Comment: How do i setup packet filter?

Comment: How do I edit ssh-config?

Comment: You should ask separate question, don't use comments for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every access list is by default ended with `deny all all`.

When you enable `ufw` width any rules to `allow` some traffic all is in `deny` state.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
69                         ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       213.xxx.xxx.xxx
80/tcp                     ALLOW       194.247.xxx.xxx
21/tcp                     ALLOW       194.247.xxx.xxx
69 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

This rules accept any on port 69, any on port 53, ssh from 213.xxx.xxx.xxx, 80 and 21 from 194.247.xxx.xxx ... **and deny any other inbound traffic**

Edit 1

When enable `ufw` without any `allow` rule everithing is `deny`.

Complete command for rule in `ufw` is

```
sudo ufw [--dry-run] [delete] [insert NUM]  allow|deny|reject|limit  [in|out on INTERFACE] [log|log-all] [proto protocol] [from ADDRESS [port PORT]][to ADDRESS [port PORT]]
```

Based on this rule template you can allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 80 with this rule

for specific host

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any port 80
```

if you wont to allow any to access your web server

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 80
```

if you wish to allow access from specific network

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy to any port 80
```

where

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - represent network ip

yy - represent network mask

If you have `DNS`service on server use make rule for `port 53` and `proto tcp` and `proto udp`.

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy to any port 53
sudo ufw allow proto udp from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy to any port 53
```

Comment: ERROR: Need 'to' or 'from' clause

Comment: I wanna lock down everything accept 80 (thats the net right?) and dns ( I assume is essential?)  I do not understand thgats why i ask

Comment: I make edit 1 in my Answer.

Comment: Ok I did this "sudo ufw enable denyall and the status report is this 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
53                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
51                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
51 (v6)

Comment: I'm home PC user just looking fior a better / more secure OS and Ubuntu is my choice to learn, sorry if i confuse I am old it hard to understand